# htaccess, Regex, Rewrite URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

hmm I have a problem with my .htaccess, I wanted to rewrite this:

> http://domain.com/a/thread-103518.html#103518

to this

> http://domain.com/a/103518

In other words... I want to delete the "thread-" and everything after the "." The /a/ must be variable... there are other forums with /bla/ and /code/

Do you have a clue for me? Thank you

My .htaccess right now:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index.php 
> RewriteRule
>   ^index.php/?(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: **Please clarify** which URL is the one "coming in from the wild", and which is your desired _output_ of .htaccess. All too often I see requests to "rewrite [dynamic format] URI to [SEO format]", when the desired action is actually the opposite. If `thread-103518.html` is a real page, and `103518` is SEO format, you want to rewrite the latter to the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `.htaccess` file in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/thread-(\d+) $1/$2? [DPI,L,R]
```

Tested in Apache 2.2 and 2.4 :)

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: thank you for the fast answer... the redirect work but now I have a DC issue.
My .htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/thread-(\d+) $1/$2? [DPI,L]

http://domain.com/a/thread-103518.html#103518 AND
http://domain.com/a/103518 are now possible, but I only want the second URL

Comment: I thought you said `http://domain.com/a/thread-103518.html#103518` should redirect to `http://domain.com/a/103518`. Not understanding, that's not the question anymore?

Comment: the link now works but you can enter the site with http://domain.com/a/thread-103518.html#103518 and http://domain.com/a/103518 . on a click at the http://domain.com/a/thread-103518.html#103518 Link, I want a redirect and URL rewrite on http://domain.com/a/103518

Comment: I think I understood. I added an `R` in the flags `[DPI,L,R]`. Now it will redirect and the url in the browser will also change. Let me know if this is what you're looking for. :)

Comment: perfect! with the R Tag it works perfect. thank you!

Comment: Ahh I have another issue... http://domain.com/resolve/b/7505541 should be redirected to http://domain.com/b/7505541 ... what I have todo?

Comment: Hey Dolan, could you please ask another question? It's really hard to troubleshoot extended questions in the comments. Thanks! :)

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916495/htaccess-amazon-affiliate-and-pagination